# Add values in the table and change the corresponding date range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my pre condition.

```
user_id  | module_start_date | module_end_date | loading
 6       | 01-01-2013        | 31-01-2013      | 0.4
 6       | 16-01-2013        | 31-01-2013      | 0.2
 6       | 01-03-2013        | 15-03-2013      | 0.7
 6       | 30-01-2013        | 30-01-2013      | 0.5
```

i have to add loading and change the dates range as shown.
with same start_date and end_date it is possible to add facing issues in the above condition.

Note:-there might be more than one users .

```
user_id   |  module_start_date| module_end_date | loading
  6       | 01-01-2013        | 15-01-2013      | 0.4
  6       | 16-01-2013        | 29-01-2013      | 0.6
  6       | 30-01-2013        | 30-01-2013      | 1.1
  6       | 31-01-2013        | 31-01-2013      | 0.6
  6       | 01-03-2013        | 15-03-2013      | 0.7
```

Comment: 1) Your question is very unclear. 2) What have you tried?

Comment: 1)i have to add loading whch is different for different range. now the issue is the date range may fluctuate,i need to sum it up all loading and make different range for comman dates. 2) when start date and end date are same i can add by sum(loading) and grouping them by group by start_date,end_date

Comment: Shouldn't the `loading` for January actually be this: `01-01, 15-01, 0.4`, `16-01, 29-01, 0.6`, `30-01, 30-01, 1.1`, `31-01, 31-01, 0.6`?

Comment: @ Andriy: yes you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a little bit easier if your end dates were exclusive. Nevertheless, here's a plan:

1. Temporarily increase the end date in every range, so that it becomes exclusive.
2. Put all the start and end dates into one list and pull the distinct dates only.
3. Get every two dates next to each other to form a new range.
4. Inner join the new range list to the one with increased end dates, group by the new ranges and get the totals for `loading`.
5. Convert the new ranges to the original "all-inclusive" format by decreasing every end date by 1.

This is an implementation of the above plan:

```
WITH converted AS (
  -- #1
  SELECT
    user_id,
    module_start_date,
    module_end_date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, module_end_date),
    loading
  FROM atable
),
datesranked AS (
  -- #2
  SELECT
    c.user_id,
    x.date,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.user_id ORDER BY x.date)
  FROM converted AS c
  CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES (c.module_start_date), (c.module_end_date)
  ) AS x (date)
  GROUP BY
    c.user_id,
    x.date
),
newranges AS (
  -- #3
  SELECT
    d1.user_id,
    module_start_date = d1.date,
    module_end_date   = d2.date
  FROM
  datesranked AS d1
  INNER JOIN datesranked AS d2
    ON d1.user_id = d2.user_id
    AND d1.rnk = d2.rnk - 1
),
totals AS (
  -- #4 & #5
  SELECT
    new.user_id,
    new.module_start_date,
    module_end_date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, new.module_end_date),
    loading = SUM(old.loading)
  FROM newranges AS new
  INNER JOIN converted AS old
    ON new.user_id = old.user_id
    AND new.module_end_date > old.module_start_date
    AND new.module_start_date < old.module_end_date
  GROUP BY
    new.user_id,
    new.module_start_date,
    new.module_end_date
)
SELECT *
FROM totals
;
```

And here's a [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc8d4/1) for the above implementation.